# How to make a grid In matlab with loop

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to make a grid (Uniform Mapping) in matlab without Meshgrid.

I have make grid with meshgrid but now I just want to make it with a loop or any Second Method (without meshgrid)

This is my code using meshgrid:

```
  figure(6)
  [X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:0.1:1, -1:0.1:1)
  plot(X,Y,'k-')
  hold on
  plot(Y,X,'k-');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `repmat`, or multiply by `ones` vectors for even more basic functionality:

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
y = -1:0.1:1;
% with repmat
X1 = repmat(x(:)',[numel(y),1]);
Y1 = repmat(y(:),[1,numel(x)]);
% multiply with ones
X2 = ones(numel(y),1)*x(:)';
Y2 = y(:)*ones(1,numel(x));
% meshgrid
[X3,Y3] = meshgrid(x, y);
isequal(X1,X2,X3) && isequal(Y1,Y2,Y3) % true

plot(X1,Y1,'k');
hold on
plot(Y1,X1,'k');
```

Comment: depends what do you want to plot. if you want vertical lines do `plot(X1,Y1,'k-')`. do you plan to plot some surface with these grids?

Comment: No i dont , just i want to design the same previously grid with other method.. i use plot(X1,Y1,'k-') but the vertical lines doesnt show , the code :
      x = -1:0.1:1;
      y = -1:0.1:1;
      % with repmat
      X1 = repmat(x(:)',[numel(y),1]);
      Y1 = repmat(y(:),[1,numel(x)]);
      plot(X1,Y1,'k-')

Comment: The result is identical to what you are getting from meshgrid so it must be another issue in your code. Maybe you're plotting something afterwards without doing 'hold on'?